# Parse an entire folder on the Windows as a Stream

Tags: c#, file, directory, filestream, memorystream

I am trying to convert a folder & it's contents (*files & sub-folders*) to a single stream which will be returned to some application. The problem is that I cannot compress the folder. Now, I want to know that whether there's a way to modify the attributes or type of a folder so that it will be treated as a single but unknown file. So that I can read it using a single FILESTREAM object.

Another way that I could think of is to return an array of stream which will contain the stream of all the files inside the root folders & sub-folders. Along with that a text/xml file also in stream, which will store the location of each file inside the Stream array.

Comment: I'm almost certain what you ask is impossible. You have to deal with a folder's files independently.

Comment: What's the point of this? Perhaps you should rather tell us what exactly you want to achieve with this.

Comment: The purpose is to send an entire directory as a stream to another application (not a dot net application) which will then parse the stream

Comment: @user2223043 And why can't you just then read file for file and send it in a stream?

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for doesn't exist; options:

- use something like the pkzip algorithm / format (lots of existing implementations of that exist), but with compression disabled (since you state that is problematic)
- write your own framing method, perhaps (off the top of my head) {num bytes in relative path}{relative path as UTF-8}{num bytes in payload}{payload} (repeat per file) and write some code to lazily stream the data as such
- reconsider the design (i.e. make it so you don't need this)

Comment: I guess I have to go with your second option as changing the design option is not in my hand. Actually it is this that I tried to emphasis on the 2nd para of my problem's statement. Just wanted to get some advice on this issue. Thanks..